# Issue updating highcharts from aqi.json file using Raspberry Pi

Tags: html, json, highcharts, raspberry-pi4

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


</head>
<script>
$.getJSON('./aqi.json', function(data) {

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
      
????
????
????
????
    
</script>
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>

What to put in script?
```

Here is my aqi.json file:
[{"pm10": 1.5, "pm25": 0.5, "time": "07.03.2021 15:45:21"}, {"pm25": 0.4, "pm10": 1.4, "time": "07.03.2021 15:55:11"}, {"pm10": 1.0, "pm25": 0.6, "time": "18.03.2021 23:09:13"}, {"pm25": 0.5, "pm10": 0.9, "time": "18.03.2021 23:10:45"}, {"pm10": 1.0, "pm25": 0.5, "time": "18.03.2021 23:12:17"}, {"pm25": 0.5, "pm10": 0.9, "time": "18.03.2021 23:13:49"}, {"pm10": 0.6, "pm25": 0.4, "time": "18.03.2021 23:15:21"}, {"pm25": 0.4, "pm10": 0.6, "time": "18.03.2021 23:16:53"}, {"pm10": 0.6, "pm25": 0.4, "time": "18.03.2021 23:18:25"}, {"pm25": 0.5, "pm10": 0.9, "time": "18.03.2021 23:19:57"}, {"pm10": 1.0, "pm25": 0.4, "time": "18.03.2021 23:21:29"}, {"pm25": 0.5, "pm10": 2.0, "time": "21.03.2021 23:26:37"}, {"pm10": 2.8, "pm25": 0.5, "time": "21.03.2021 23:28:09"}, {"pm25": 0.6, "pm10": 2.5, "time": "21.03.2021 23:29:41"}, {"pm10": 1.8, "pm25": 0.4, "time": "21.03.2021 23:31:13"}]

Answer (score 0):

After fetching your data you will need to parse it into proper Highcharts format.

```
let data = [{
  "pm10": 1.5,
  "pm25": 0.5,
  "time": "07.03.2021 15:45:21"
}, {
  "pm25": 0.4,
  "pm10": 1.4,
  "time": "07.03.2021 15:55:11"
}, {
  "pm10": 1.0,
  "pm25": 0.6,
  "time": "18.03.2021 23:09:13"
}, {
  "pm25": 0.5,
  "pm10": 0.9,
  "time": "18.03.2021 23:10:45"
}, {
  "pm10": 1.0,
  "pm25": 0.5,
  "time": "18.03.2021 23:12:17"
}, {
  "pm25": 0.5,
  "pm10": 0.9,
  "time": "18.03.2021 23:13:49"
}, {
  "pm10": 0.6,
  "pm25": 0.4,
  "time": "18.03.2021 23:15:21"
}, {
  "pm25": 0.4,
  "pm10": 0.6,
  "time": "18.03.2021 23:16:53"
}, {
  "pm10": 0.6,
  "pm25": 0.4,
  "time": "18.03.2021 23:18:25"
}, {
  "pm25": 0.5,
  "pm10": 0.9,
  "time": "18.03.2021 23:19:57"
}, {
  "pm10": 1.0,
  "pm25": 0.4,
  "time": "18.03.2021 23:21:29"
}, {
  "pm25": 0.5,
  "pm10": 2.0,
  "time": "21.03.2021 23:26:37"
}, {
  "pm10": 2.8,
  "pm25": 0.5,
  "time": "21.03.2021 23:28:09"
}, {
  "pm25": 0.6,
  "pm10": 2.5,
  "time": "21.03.2021 23:29:41"
}, {
  "pm10": 1.8,
  "pm25": 0.4,
  "time": "21.03.2021 23:31:13"
}];

const pm25 = data.map(d => [d.time, d.pm25]);
const pm10 = data.map(d => [d.time, d.pm10]);

Highcharts.chart('container', {

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'pm25',
    data: pm25,
  }, {
    name: 'pm10',
    data: pm10
  }]
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m9awh4ok/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

If you want to use the `datetime` type for the xAxis you will need to change your date format into the milliseconds or other accepted by UTC standard.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! This helped me move on to a fully functional line chart.

Comment: @ddajj could you accept the answer? Might be useful for other users.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, the solution you suggested was fully acceptable. BTW, is it possible to filter one result pr day? I was thinking about this, maybe decrease number of measurements per second?